# Want to use the output created from first def as input variables for another second def within class in python

Tags: python, function, class, input, output

Here I have created the output x from first def(null_checking) function and want to **use the same output** (x) **as input** for second def(variance) within class. I tried a lot but couldnot.

```
#import dependencies
#import dependencies
from optparse import Values
from re import X
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant
import pandas as pd

from .prac import checking_null

#import datasets
datasets = pd.read_csv('Car_sales.csv')
datasets

features = ['Fuel_efficiency', 'Power_perf_factor', 'Engine_size', 'Horsepower', 'Fuel_capacity', 'Curb_weight']
features

class extraction():
    def __init__(self, datasets, features):
        self.features = features
        self.datasets = datasets
        #checking and removing null rows present in the dataframe
    def null_checking(self):
        datasets1 = self.datasets[self.features]
        print(datasets1)
        for items, x in enumerate(datasets1):
            if items =='True':
                continue
            x = datasets1.dropna(axis=0)
            print(x)
        #calculating variance inflation factorss
    def variance(self):
        x.inner_display()
        #we need intercept for calculating variance inflation factor
        x['intercept'] = 1
        print(x)
        #Making the new dataframe
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        df['variables'] = x.columns
        df['VIF'] = [variance_inflation_factor(x, i) for i in range(x.shape[1])]
        print(df)
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want `variance` called for each `x` that is printed?

Comment: Uh, what is your question? Either have the first method `return` the value, and call it from the second; or save the value as an attribute `self.x` (or `self._x` if you want to mark it as private) - you then have to separately ensure it's populated before you call the second method; perhaps call it from `__init__` to ensure this?